# Small linear relations between primitive Pythagorean triples $\mathsf I$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sums-of-squares, probabilistic-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Say $a^2+b^2=c^2$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple. Then consider the Linear Diophantine Equation
$$ua^2+vb^2+xab+ybc+zca=0$$ where $(u,v,x, y, z)\in\mathbb Z^4$ are variables. If $(u,v,x, y, z)\neq(0,0,0,0,0)$ then can we say anything about $\|(u,v,x, y, z)\|_\infty$ or the probability distribution of $\|(u,v,x, y, z)\|_\infty$?

By this I mean can $\|(u,v,x, y, z)\|_\infty$ be much smaller than $\sqrt{\max(a^2,b^2)}$?

Comment: Sorry, how do you want to get any small solution if $a|y,b|z$ and $c|x$ provided $(a,b)=1$?

Comment: $ybc=-a(xb+zc)$, so $a|ybc$. If $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime then $a|y$ is nesessary.

Comment: @PavelKozlov I updated and for this I am pretty sure we can do better that $\sqrt{\max(a^2,b^2)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when $m>n>0$ and
$$ a = m^2 - n^2 $$
$$ b = 2mn $$
$$ c = m^2 + n^2 $$
then
$$ -n a^2 +(m-n)b^2 - n ab +(m-n)bc - n ca = 0  $$
or  quintuple
$$ -n, m-n, -n, m-n, -n $$

There is a second pattern that gives the same optimum when $n$ is small, quintuple
$$ -2n, m-n, m-n, m-n, -2n $$

Comment: Do we always such $m,n$?

Comment: @VS. of course. It's well-known that every primitive Pythagorean triple is given by those formula (with $\gcd(m,n)=1$, and $m,n$ not both odd).

Comment: @WillJagy So $\sqrt{\max(|a|,|b|)}$ is the correct scale up to constants?

Comment: @WillJagy Now I am really curious. What about $ua+vb+zc=0$ with $(u,v,z)\neq(0,0,0)$? Is $\|(u,v,z)\|_\infty$ also at least $\sqrt{\max(|a|,|b|)}$ or should the scale (disregarding constants) be smaller (perhaps $\sqrt[3]{\max(|a|,|b|)}$)?

Comment: @WillJagy https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357444/small-linear-relations-between-primitive-pythagorean-triples-mathsfii