# Small linear relations between primitive Pythagorean triples $\mathsf{II}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, probabilistic-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

WillJagy answered a linear relation question on Pythagorean Triples in [Small linear relations between primitive Pythagorean triples $\mathsf I$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357219/small-linear-relations-between-primitive-pythagorean-triples).

Now let $a^2+b^2=c^2$ be a primitive Pythagorean triple and then consider the Linear Diophantine Equation $ua+vb+zc=0$ where $(u,v,z)\in\mathbb Z^3$ are variables. If $(u,v,z)\neq(0,0,0)$ then:

1. Is $\|(u,v,z)\|_\infty$ at least $\sqrt{\max(|a|,|b|)}$ up to constant factors or should the scale (disregarding constants) be smaller (perhaps $\sqrt[3]{\max(|a|,|b|)}$)?
2. What is the distribution of $\|(u,v,z)\|_\infty$?

Note if it were $ua^2+vb^2+zc^2=0$ then the answer is $O(1)$ since $(u,v,z)=(1,1,-1)$ suffices.

---

This is what I have
$$ a = m^2 - n^2 $$
$$ b = 2mn $$
$$ c = m^2 + n^2 $$
then
$$ n(m^2 - n^2 ) +(-m)(2mn) + n(m^2 + n^2) = 0  $$
or  triple
$$(u,v,z)=(n,-m,n)$$ works and this gives morally $\sqrt{\max(|a|,|b|)}$ ($(m,n,-m)$ also works to give morally $\sqrt{\max(|a|,|b|)}$). Could there be something smaller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, the minimal $\|(u,v,z)\|_\infty$ is within a constant factor of
   $\sqrt{|c|}$ (equivalently, of $\sqrt{\max(|a|,|b|)}$.

The orthogonal complement of $(a,b,c) = (m^2-n^2, 2mn, m^2+n^2)$
contains the independent integer vectors 
$v_1 := (n,-m,n)$ (which you found) and $v_2 := (m,n,-m)$.
Their $\bf Z$-span is the full integral complement of $(a,b,c)$,
for example because that span has discriminant
$$
\|v_1\|_2^2 \|v_2\|_2^2 - \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle^2
= 2(m^2+n^2)^2 
$$
which equals $a^2+b^2+c^2 = \|(a,b,c)\|_2^2$.
Moreover, $(v_1,v_2)$ is a reduced basis, because
$|\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle| = mn$ is less than $(m^2+n^2)/2$, 
and thus less than both $ \frac12 \|v_1\|_2^2$ and $\frac12 \|v_2\|_2^2$.
Therefore the minimal $\|(u,v,z)\|_2$ exceeds 
$\sqrt{m^2+n^2} = \sqrt{|c|}$, whence the same is true
of $\|(u,v,z)\|_\infty$ within a constant factor.  **QED**

Comment: @NoamElkies Fastest accept. However I am wondering if we take unbalanced diophantine equations $au+bv+c^2z=0$ or $a^2u+b^2v+cz=0$ or any $a^tu+b^{t'}v+c^{t''}z=0$ where $t,t',t''\in\{1,2\}$ and $1<tt't''<8$ also will we get similar $\sqrt{\max(|a|,|b|)}$ bounds? At lower limit $tt't''=1$ we get this bound and at upper limit $tt't''=8$ we get $O(1)$. Perhaps there is some interpolating rule? Or perhaps $\sqrt{\max(|a|,|b|)}$ until at $8$? Should I post a new post?

Comment: That's a different question (and I'm can't guess the motivation for
those particular "unbalanced diophantines").  Once we have a reduced
basis for the lattice, you can use it to start analyzing such equations
where you require one or more of the coordinates to be square.

Comment: I see the point of analyzing that way however posted https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357507/small-linear-relations-between-primitive-pythagorean-triples-mathsfiii. Motivation is to see if it might give a smaller relations that cannot be ordinarily seen with just probabilistic analysis. I think only at $8$ it breaks down and at every value from $\{1,2,4\}$ it remains $\Omega(\sqrt{\max(|a|,|b|)})$ but I do not see a reason why it should fall only at $8$.

Comment: Denote $u_1,\dots,u_{n-1}$ to be basis of orthogonal complement of a vector $v\in\mathbb Z^n$. 1.) Then is there a definition of discriminant wrt the basis that is defined? 2. Also discriminant same as $\|v\|_2^2$ implies $\mathbb Z$-span of basis spans the full integral complement? 3. Also is there a general relation between reduced basis and discriminant? Any references for these that will help?

Comment: 1) Discriminant of ${\bf Z}$-span of any vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ =
determinant of Gram matrix $(\langle v_i, v_j\rangle)$.
This is the formula for any quadratic form. 2) It is known that
if $v \in {\bf Z}^n$ is primitive (not $cv'$ for some $c>1$ and
integer vector $v'$) then its orthogonal complement has discriminant $\|v\|_2^2$.
So if you've found $n-1$ vectors with the same discriminant
you've got everything.  (A superlattice of index $d>1$ would have discriminant
$d^2$ times smaller.)  3) Not sure what exactly the first question means.
For the second, [cont'd]

Comment: these days I'm even less able to dig up references than usual, but
all this can surely be found in "SPLAG" = Conway and Sloane's
*Sphere Packings, Lattices, and Groups*, not far from the beginning.

Comment: $(v_1,v_2)$ is reduced basis since inner product magnitude is less than $\frac{\min_i\|v_i\|_2^2}2$. For $n$ dimensions is it pairwise inner product $|\langle v_i,v_j\rangle|<\min_{k\in\{1,\dots,\}}\frac{\|v_k\|_2^2}2$ or is it just $|\langle v_i,v_j\rangle|<\min(\frac{\|v_1\|_2^2}2,\frac{\|v_2\|_2^2}2)$?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365032/how-small-do-linear-diophantine-solutions-shrink-when-solutions-are-small-linear